# MVC Pattern for Java Application to Display Serial Port Data

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, serial-port, processing

I would like to have a Java Application to display data from Serial Port in a Processing Sketch.

Now I wrote a program that is able to connect to the Serial Port and print in the console of Eclipse the data read from the serial port.

This program looks a little bit messy and for this reason me and my group leader were thinking to use a Model-View-Controller pattern to let the program look more readable

Do you have some hints, code, web pages etc which could help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have few queries before I can answer your quesyion. Why you are thinking of using MVC framework? Are you planning to use it as a web application? Why not a thick client like Swing instead of thin client?

Regards,

Bipul Sinha

Comment: I´m not an expert of Java. My group leader suggested me to use it.

In this way we could have something like: 
MODEL: Data storage etc...
Control: SerialCommunication, Actions performed when a user press a button
View: Processing Sketch to view the messages in a graph...

Do you think there is an easier way?

It has not to go on a Web .

Comment: I would suggest to use something like Swing instead of web-application. You can use an IDE like NetBeans to help you code. It provides Drag-Drop feature and generates all boiler plate code for you.

Comment: I´m using Swing over Eclipse. Is it the same?Has it also something to drag and drop buttons and stuff like that?

Comment: If you are using Swing use NetBeans instead.

Comment: Why? Can you explain that to me please?

Comment: Yes, because NetBeans provides you drag-drop features and generate all your boiler-plate code. It is class one IDE for Swing development as compared to Eclipse.